# Make images load when they enter visible section of browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image

I was browsing around the web and I saw something I've never seen before.
on this site:
http://blogof.francescomugnai.com/2009/04/mega-roundup-of-geektool-scripts-inspiration-gallery/

When you navigate down the page, the images only load when they are in the visible portion of the browser.
I have never seen this before and was wondering if anyone else has and how exactly one would do it.

I'm guessing this is some sort of Wordpress plugin (that's what he's using) but I'm not sure.
Is it javascript?  Are they actually loading on page load but just become visible later for a "snazzy" effect or is this actually useful for quicker page load times?

Comment: As a side note, cellphones use less power if you do all your downloading in one burst instead of many brief bursts. This plugin would likely reduce cellphone battery life for your users. Small impact I assume, but notable. Here's a Tech Talk that does much more serious measurements on this than I could ever do: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Il4swGfTOSM They basically recommend that all below-the-fold content load all at once as a secondary download after the user has scrolled a bit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

LazyLoad is no longer available according to the website. Apparently the code no longer works on new browsers and the author doesn't have time to update it.

The "appear" plug in is working well for me.

http://plugins.jquery.com/appear/

It allows you to specify a callback function for an element. The callback function is called when the element appears into view. From the site:

```
$('#foo').appear(function() {
  $(this).text('Hello world');
});
```

Comment: At the time I wrote my answer (around 9 months ago), LazyLoad was not being maintained by its author. Perhaps the author has now started working on it again. Please keep in mind the date that a question was answered.

Comment: jquery-appear has disappeared (hah!) from Google Code. LazyLoad appears (hah!) to have resurrected, see http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload.

Answer (score 15):

> "wp-content/plugins/jquery-image-lazy-loading"
>
> Lazy loader is a jQuery plugin written
>   in JavaScript. It delays loading of
>   images in (long) web pages. Images
>   outside of viewport (visible part of
>   web page) wont be loaded before user
>   scrolls to them. This is opposite of
>   image preloading.
>
> Using lazy load on long web pages
>   containing many large images makes the
>   page load faster. Browser will be in
>   ready state after loading visible
>   images. In some cases it can also help
>   to reduce server load.

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

So it seems it goes through every image specified or inside of the context of an element and replaces the src with a placeholder gif before the images fully load, saves the original URI and when the image is "visible" it replaces the placeholder with the real image.

Comment: The LazyLoad plugin is no longer available according to its website. See my answer below.

Comment: Lazy Load has always been available. It was never removed. However new browser insist loading images even when src attribute is removed. Thus you now have to modify HTML in order for it to work. I finally had time to update documentation. Also removed all old code which does not work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source of the page you referenced, it contains this bit of code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  jQuery(".SC img").lazyload({
    effect:"fadeIn",
    placeholder: "http://blogof.francescomugnai.com/wp-content/plugins/jquery-image-lazy-loading/images/grey.gif"
  });
});
```

I suspect that's how they're accomplishing the effect.  It uses the jQuery LazyLoad plugin, which can be found here:

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Answer (score 1):

As Sanjay pointed out, the jQuery LazyLoad plugin from Applesiini no longer works. Here is another jQuery plugin that I found. Just another option in addition to **jQuery Appear**.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/LazyLoadOnScroll

http://ivorycity.com/blog/2011/04/19/jquery-lazy-loader-load-html-and-images-on-scroll/