# Suppose I have a list of 500 thumbnails followed by the title. How do I load the images as the user scrolls down? (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, templates, lazy-loading

In mobile, the internet is slow. If I have a list of 500 images, this is going to take forever to load.  I'd like to load the title of the image in a list, but as the user scrolls down, I want to start loading/downloading the `<img>` tag. How do I use Javascript/Jquery to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking a look at this jQuery plugin:

[Lazy Loading](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)

Answer (score 0):

The Lazy Load Plugin for jQuery should do what you need to do. http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Answer (score 0):

Now, see [Make images load when they enter visible section of browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736215/make-images-load-when-they-enter-visible-section-of-browser?lq=1); apparently lazyload itself no longer works or is no longer available, but this gives other substitutes.