# Load image only when it is viewable?

Tags: javascript, html

I saw some web page which has a large number of images, only the images inside the scrolled viewport is displayed, for the outside images, when I scroll down to it, it will be loaded.

How that can be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suppose I have a list of 500 thumbnails followed by the title. How do I load the images as the user scrolls down? (JQuery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375703/suppose-i-have-a-list-of-500-thumbnails-followed-by-the-title-how-do-i-load-the)

Comment: another lazyload solution: http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/lazyload3.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this jquery lazy load plugin, it works great, is very customizable,
and you dont have to deal with cross browser issues :

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/lazyload

Answer (score 1):

The magic word is "Lazy loading". I have no experience with it but [this plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) is one of the most popular solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at the [following article](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/load-content-while-scrolling-with-jquery/) which uses jquery.