# Lazyloading Google API not working

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading

Here's the deal. I've tried a number of methods of lazy loading the Google Maps API JavaScript, and every time in do it, with any Lazy Loader I use, FireFox "blocks." It lazy loads just fine in Chrome.

What I mean by "blocks" is that the elements in the HTML don't display, and instead, the browsers spin trying to make a connection to download the Maps JavaScript.

The code follows. Put it in an HTML file and open it in your browser:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://github.com/rgrove/lazyload/raw/master/lazyload.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        Open your console. Wait for "entering debugger..." message.<br />
        You can't see me in FireFox, can you?
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // If I remove the `sensor` from the query string key and value, 
            // Google rejects the request and alert() does occur
            LazyLoad.js("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false", function() {
                console.log("entering debugger...");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In Chrome, I see the "Open your console..." contents of the page, and the JavaScript is requested and downloaded, async, in the background.

In FireFox, the "Open your console..." contents never appear, and it hangs (status bar says "Read" from a Google DNS), never finishing or displaying the page contents.

Comment: Not the answer to your question exactly, but I do want to say that http://headjs.com/ is friggin awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need to write your own loader? What about using a previously tested implementation: [Lazy Load](https://github.com/rgrove/lazyload/)

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to load Google Maps on demand? To load the API dynamically, pass a callback parameter, as shown on the [Example](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/callback/callback_delayed.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to rename your LazyLoad script, because [it already exists.](http://wonko.com/post/painless_javascript_lazy_loading_with_lazyload) :) Speaking of which, it already exists, so why write it again?

If you just want to see how it's done, the [source code](http://cdn.wonko.com/lazyload/1.0.4/lazyload.js) is available.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, why reinvent the wheel. You seem to be using jQuery.
try this plugin:
[Load image only when it is viewable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983900/load-image-only-when-it-is-viewable/4983912#4983912)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:
Check the URL:'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true'
You would find main.js is being imported by it . A simple getScript for sensor=true will not give whole google object so next import also required.

```
  var t=setTimeout(function(){
    jQuery.getScript('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true');
    jQuery.getScript('http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/10/20/main.js');
  },1000);
```

PS: Similar issue thread [Lazy loading google map api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476690/lazy-loading-google-map-api)