# Lazy loading google map api

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading

I want to lazy load all the 3rd party JS/CSS after my home page is displayed since the external plugins etc are used when user navigates away from home page onto some specific module.

So far I have succeeded for normal .js & .css external libraries thanx to http://wonko.com/post/lazyload-200-released

However this fails for a path like this http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true

Code:

```
   LazyLoad.js('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true', function () {
   alert('Your JS has been loaded');
   });
```

I think the solution would be how to lazy-load web url?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something like:

```
$.getScript('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true');
```

using jQuery. The [API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) will give details of the call back. Else Google may have some mechanism requiring it to be present from load. Just a guess.

Comment: when i watch this in firebug it does give the script but does not load the script in my code. I am executing this line after all my .js/.css is lazy loaded.

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution:
Check the URL:'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true'
You would find main.js is being imported by it . A simple getScript for sensor=true will not give whole google object so next import also required.

```
  var t=setTimeout(function(){
    jQuery.getScript('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true');
    jQuery.getScript('http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/10/20/main.js');
  },1000);
```

Comment: Putting this in the document ready was the idea behind my answer and should have the same result as a timeout which are best avoided in my opinion...