# How to load images dynamically (or lazily) when users scrolls them into view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, lazy-loading

I've noticed this in numerous "modern" websites (e.g. facebook and google image search) where the images below the fold load only when user scrolls down the page enough to bring them inside the visible viewport region (**upon view source, the page shows *X* number of `<img>` tags but they are not fetched from the server straight away**). What is this technique called, how does it work and in how many browsers does it work. And is there a jQuery plugin that can achieve this behavior with minimum coding.

## Edit

Bonus: can someone explain if there is a "onScrolledIntoView" or similar event for HTML elements. If not, how do these plugins work?

Comment: Do you need only image lazy loading ? If you need content lazy loading, infinite scroll plugin is the right answer

Comment: @rsp @jwegner @Nicholas am sorry, but that is not what Salman is asking.

Comment: @soju: I am only interested in lazy loading images; but I may look at other possibilities sometime in the (fairly distant) future.

Comment: Makes you wonder why a browser's default behaviour isn't to only load images that are visible. Imagine how much bandwidth might have been saved in the last 18 years if that was the case!

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736215/make-images-load-when-they-enter-visible-section-of-browser

Comment: While I understand the reason behind lazy loading... I honestly can't stand it when I visit a site that utilizes that method. The blinking of the images drives me nuts! :)

Comment: @MatthewLock Because it would require all web developers to code their site with this in mind -- if they didn't, the layout of the page would jump and change as the user scrolled down. It would be great if that was the case, but I can't see it becoming standard any time soon.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Some of the answers here are for infinite page. What Salman is asking is lazy loading of images.

[Plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)

[Demo](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled.html)

EDIT: **How do these plugins work?**

This is a simplified explanation:

1. Find window size and find the position of all images and their sizes
2. If the image is not within the window size, replace it with a placeholder of same size
3. When user scrolls down, and position of image < scroll + window height, the image is loaded

Comment: In application, wouldn't they work the same?  An infinite scroll on a single column of images would be the same as lazy loading them, right?  Perhaps I'm confused.

Comment: @jwegner Infinite scroll would let you add new items to the bottom of the page when the user reached (or approached) the bottom. Lazy-loaded images could have placeholders of the same dimensions on the page, with the images themselves loaded on scroll. So, the latter could lazy load without affecting the page layout.

Comment: This is working fine on desktop browsers and iOS but doesn't work on android (including 3.x/4.x).  Any idea why?  is the scroll event not supported?

Comment: I was going through the documentation for this plugin and it seems to be pretty awesome. Going to use this on my next project.

Comment: here's a related plugin, which probably works about the same way: http://afarkas.github.io/lazysizes/ except I believe it's much more robust and uses more of what's already there (no need for placeholder, for instance, but you can have it if you want).

Comment: Works well with datatables, until you sort a column, then it stops working. :(

Comment: I know this is a bit old question to comment on but to "load" the image is replacing `src` attribute instead of a placeholder is enough?

Comment: Will this help my page load faster if I'm using several images in one page? Or the images are loaded at the beginning anyway and just being shown while scrolling?

Answer (score 16):

I came up with my own basic method which seems to work fine (so far). There's probably a dozen things some of the popular scripts address that I haven't thought of.

**Note** - This solution is fast and easy to implement but of course not great for performance. Definitely look into the new [Intersection Observer](https://w3c.github.io/IntersectionObserver/) as mentioned by [Apoorv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45946324/3377049) and explained by [developers.google](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/intersectionobserver) if performance is an issue.

**The JQuery**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $.each($('img'), function() {
        if ( $(this).attr('data-src') && $(this).offset().top < ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() + 100) ) {
            var source = $(this).data('src');
            $(this).attr('src', source);
            $(this).removeAttr('data-src');
        }
    })
})
```

Sample html code

```
<div>
    <img src="" data-src="pathtoyour/image1.jpg">
    <img src="" data-src="pathtoyour/image2.jpg">
    <img src="" data-src="pathtoyour/image3.jpg">
</div>
```

**Explained**

When the page is scrolled each image on the page is checked..

`$(this).attr('data-src')` - if the image has the attribute `data-src`

and how far those images are from the bottom of the window..

`$(this).offset().top < ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() + 100)`

adjust the + 100 to whatever you like (- 100 for example)

`var source = $(this).data('src');` - gets the value of `data-src=` aka the image url

`$(this).attr('src', source);` - puts that value into the `src=`

`$(this).removeAttr('data-src');` - removes the data-src attribute (so your browser doesn't waste resources messing with the images that have already loaded)

**Adding To Existing Code**

To convert your html, in an editor just search and replace `src="` with `src="" data-src="`

Comment: perfect. bless fam 

Answer (score 10):

<sup>(**Edit:** replaced broken links with archived copies)</sup>

Dave Artz of AOL gave a great talk on optimization at jQuery Conference Boston last year. AOL uses a tool called Sonar for on-demand loading based on scroll position. Check the code for the particulars of how it compares scrollTop  (and others) to the element offset to detect if part or all of the element is visible.

[jQuery Sonar](https://web.archive.org/web/20151011094553/http://www.artzstudio.com/files/jquery-boston-2010/jquery.sonar)

Dave talks about Sonar in [these slides](https://web.archive.org/web/20170821211029/https://appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled/). Sonar starts on slide 46, while the overall "load on demand" discussion starts on slide 33.

Comment: I wonder how does this compare to Appelsinii's lazyload? Is it more lightweight? Does it work on every browser? I remember lazyload does not work on Chrome.

Answer (score 5):

There is a pretty nice infinite scroll plugin [here](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/)

I've never programmed one myself, but I would imagine this is how it works.

1. An event is bound to the the window scrolling

   ```
   $(window).scroll(myInfinteScrollFunction);
   ```
2. The called function checks if scroll top is greater than the window size

   ```
   function myInfiniteScrollFunction() {  
       if($(window).scrollTop() == $(window).height())  
       makeAjaxRequest();  
   }
   ```
3. An AJAX request is made, specifying which result # to start at, how many to grab, and any other parameters necessary for the data pull.

   ```
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url:  "myAjaxFile.php",
       data: {"resultNum": 30, "numPerPage": 50, "query": "interesting%20icons" },
       success: myInfiniteLoadFunction(msg)
   });
   ```
4. The ajax returns some (most-likely JSON formatted) content, and passes them into the loadnig function.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

You can now use `loading="lazy"` on the images as well as iframes so that it defers the loading until the user scrolls to that element.

```
<img src="http://placeimg.com/640/360/any" loading="lazy" />
```

As quoted in [MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Lazy_loading)

> **Loading attribute** The loading attribute on an  element (or the
> loading attribute on an ) can be used to instruct the browser
> to defer loading of images/iframes that are off-screen until the user
> scrolls near them.

[Can I use?](https://caniuse.com/loading-lazy-attr)

You can use on all modern browsers for the images, but iframes are experimental as of now.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&display=swap');

.scroll-down {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #037ef3;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Oswald";
  font-size: 2em;
}

.image {
  padding: 2em;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-down">
  Let me take this space so that you can scroll down
</div>
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://placeimg.com/640/360/any" loading="lazy" /> <!-- The only important part -->
</div>
```

**Tip:**

As you can see in the demo, it creates layout shift which will create a bad UX while scrolling. So try to use placeholders. Something similar like this: [NextJS Placeholder](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#placeholder)

Comment: @user1034912 I just checked the network request too. It loads the image only when I scroll down. Can you explain it a bit more so that the users can understand?

Answer (score 3):

> Lazy loading images by attaching listener to scroll events or by making use of setInterval is highly non-performant as each call to getBoundingClientRect() forces the browser to [re-layout](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a) the entire page and will introduce considerable jank to your website.

Use **[Lozad.js](https://github.com/ApoorvSaxena/lozad.js)** (just 569 bytes with no dependencies), which uses [IntersectionObserver](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/intersectionobserver) to lazy load images performantly.

Comment: [Polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/intersection-observer) can be added dynamically in case browser support isn't available

Comment: Browser support is a lot better these days - [can i use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=intersectionobserver)

Answer (score 1):

The Swiss Army knife of image lazy loading is YUI's [ImageLoader](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/imageloader/).

Because there is more to this problem than simply watching the scroll position.

Answer (score 0):

Im using [jQuery Lazy](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/). It took me about 10 minutes to test out and an hour or two to add to most of the image links on one of my websites ([CollegeCarePackages.com](http://www.CollegeCarePackages.com)). I have **NO (none/zero)** relationship of any kind to the dev, but it saved me a lot of time and basically helped improve our bounce rate for mobile users and I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This Link work for me [demo](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Smartly-Load-Images-While-Scrolling-loadScroll/)

1.Load the jQuery loadScroll plugin after jQuery library, but before the closing body tag.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="jQuery.loadScroll.js"></script>
```

2.Add the images into your webpage using Html5 data-src attribute. You can also insert placeholders using the regular img's src attribute.

```
<img data-src="1.jpg" src="Placeholder.jpg" alt="Image Alt"><img data-src="2.jpg" src="Placeholder.jpg" alt="Image Alt"><img data-src="3.jpg" src="Placeholder.jpg" alt="Image Alt">
```

3.Call the plugin on the img tags and specify the duration of the
    fadeIn effect as your images are come into view

```
$('img').loadScroll(500); // in ms
```