# How do I make image disappear when my scrollable div has reached a certain height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have a scrollable div with and arrow above and an arrow below. What I am trying to do is to make the arrow above appear after the div has reached a certain height.

here is the code that I have...

```
$("#scrolldivup").hide();
$(.section).scroll(function(){
          if($(.section).scrollTop()>1){
                $("#scrolldivup").fadeIn();
             }
             else
             {
                $("#scrolldivup").fadeOut();
             }
    });
```

".section" is the scrollable div So as soon as it scrolls more than 1 pixel I want the "#scrolldivup" to appear which by the way is an anchor tag.

Can anyone see how  my code is wrong?

Comment: jquery lazy loader : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117421/how-to-load-images-dynamically-or-lazily-when-users-scrolls-them-into-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#testdiv").hide();
 $(".section").scroll(function(){
      if($(".section").scrollTop()>1){
            $("#scrolldivup").fadeIn();
         }
         else
         {
            $("#scrolldivup").fadeOut();
         }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(.section)`
should be 
`$('.section')`