# How can I make something 'appear' when a user scrolls down?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to figure out how I can create an effect like on this site: http://ournameismud.co.uk/
The effect is when u open the page and as you scroll down, content seems to appear then. How can I achieve this effect? I know it would need CSS3 or jQuery or both. But can you please give me some detail about this?

Thank you.

Comment: It could be [lazy loading](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117421/how-to-load-images-dynamically-or-lazily-when-users-scrolls-them-into-view

Comment: aka "infinite scroll"

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is lazy load images.
Check out this post, i hope it satisfies your needs.
[How to load images dynamically (or lazily) when users scrolls them into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117421/how-to-load-images-dynamically-or-lazily-when-users-scrolls-them-into-view)

Comment: Can I also do that with divs or sections and not images? Also I've seen images or sections 'appear' from left or right, or move somehow only when u scroll down to that location. For example: https://yourkarma.com/ the router image falls down when u scroll to that position. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Yes you can do similar for divs too!

Comment: Its achievable using jQuery. You need to have a jQuery event setup when the image is scrolled into view.

Comment: when the image is scrolled into view. all you need to do then is mess with its CSS properties. in this case CSS3 properties, transformation , rotation.