# How to load images dynamically when users scrolls like in www.techlokam.in home page

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I have image loading dynamically when user scrolls the website. I have found this example in this site http://www.techlokam.in 
How is this possible with jQuery???

Comment: Exact duplicate of [How to load images dynamically (or lazily) when users scrolls them into view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117421/how-to-load-images-dynamically-or-lazily-when-users-scrolls-them-into-view)

Answer (score 0):

Its already answered here!!

[How to load images dynamically (or lazily) when users scrolls them into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117421/how-to-load-images-dynamically-or-lazily-when-users-scrolls-them-into-view)

Please be sure not submit duplicate questions!!