Upload in ajax to scroll photos inside a specific path
In my Joomla site, I have created a page where many photos will be uploaded.
These photos will be taken from a folder which is called "products" and is located in my ftp.
To foreach all the photos in this folder is easy, just do this:
$all_files = glob("products/*.*");
 for ($i=0; $i<count($all_files); $i++)
 {
  $image_name = $all_files[$i];
  echo '<img src="'.$image_name .'" alt="'.$image_name.'" />'."<br /><br />";
 }

But since there are so many photos I would like to do it exactly the way Facebook does it, which is like this:

Foreach some of the photos as soon as you open the page
The rest of the other photos (and thus the rest of the foreach) should appear when I scroll down the page

How can I do this? Any suggestions?
Thanks
Translated with DeepL.com (free version)

This is called lazy loading of images. See: Can I use lazy.

I think this topic will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117421/how-to-load-images-dynamically-or-lazily-when-users-scrolls-them-into-view

Very good! Thanks for the help!
