# Lazy Load an entire DIV and not individual images

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, lazy-loading

I have a webpage which is a side scroller. At the moment all the content loads on page load, but this is turning into a gigantic page! I applied some lazy load to images and such... but it's just not smooth and the page feels awkward trying to navigate.

There are 7 "panes" and each pane has a parent DIV tag with a unique ID. What I would like to do is when Pane 2 comes into view, a loading gif is displayed and the div is blank until all the content/imagery is loaded. When the content/imagery is loaded then the loader disappears and the content fades in. This would repeat for all panes 2 - 7.

I've looked at numerous jquery scripts and methods, but I can't just seem to wrap my head around how to make this happen specifically. It's like lazy load, but for an entire div and not just an image. I'd like the page to background load, but prevent users from for example, seeing pane 3 which has not downloaded yet, showing the awkward sight of images loading.

Is this easier then I realize? What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make images load when they enter visible section of browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736215/make-images-load-when-they-enter-visible-section-of-browser)

Answer (score 0):

there are numerous ways to achieve this, easiest one i guess is simply use jQuery get method to get actual HTML for active slide:

```
$.get('slide2.html', function(respHTML) {
   $(respHTML).appendTo($("#contentFrame"));
},'html');
```

you can select all images before appending html and preload them, there are also numerous ways to preload images

```
var respHTML = $(respHTML);
var imagesToPreload = respHTML.find('img');
var imagesPreloaded = 0;
var imagesLength = imagesToPreload.length;
imagesToPreload.each(function(i,img) {
    // preload img
    imagesPreloaded++;
    if(imagesPreloaded == imagesLength) {
       // your images are ready
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the [appear plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-appear/) for jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You may use CSS trick with transitions and media queries, similar to what I did for lazy image loading here: http://podlipensky.com/2013/06/css-only-load-images-on-demand/