# Load HTML when section in viewport

Tags: html, show, viewport

I have the following HTML that loads a CSS3 animation:

```
<div class="quote">
   <a id="dex-sign" class="play" target="_blank"></a>
</div>
```

Is there any way I can get this code to load when the relevant div is shown in the viewport? This will mean the animation starts to play when it comes into view.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make images load when they enter visible section of browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736215/make-images-load-when-they-enter-visible-section-of-browser)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using media queries in css.
For example:

```
.quote{
   display:none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:767px){
   .quote{
         display:block;
    }

 }
```